# sequelize add value to found object

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Okay so i am finding a list of something called `component`

once the result is ready my idea was to loop through the list and find all `question_answer` and then add them to the individual object. For this i tried the following:

```
    Component.findAll({include: [{all: true}], where: {module_id: module_id}}).then(function(components)
{
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
        if(components[i].dataValues.question_id != null)
        {
           Question_answer.findAll({where: {question_id: components[i].dataValues.question_id}}).then(function(answers)
            {
               var i = 0; // here i want to add the value however i cannot reach components[i]
            });
        }
    }
})
    .success(onSuccess).error(onError);
```

My problem is that it is an inner function and i am unable to reach variables outside the inner funciton.

So my question is how do i add additional values when using multiple query's?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'cant reach components[i]'. Nothing in javascript scoping should prevent you from that. However, you are overwriting the outer i by declaring `var i`, that might cause you issues?

Comment: This is happening because the second query is async and by the time you want to use component[i] your for loop has ended. Try replacing for loop with a forEach, this will create a new function for each component. But be careful at performance issues in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Model: `Component.js`

```
"use strict";
const { Model } = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class Component extends Model {
        static associate(models) {
            this.hasMany(models.Question_answer, {
                foreignKey: "question_id",
                as: 'questions'
            });
        }
    }
    Component.init({
        title: { type: DataTypes.STRING, },
        question_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, },
    }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: "Component",
        defaultScope: {
            attributes: { exclude: ["createdAt", "updatedAt"] }
        },
    });
    return Component;
};
```

Model: `Question_answer.js`

```
"use strict";
const { Model } = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class Question_answer extends Model {
 
    }
    Question_answer.init({
        testData: { type: DataTypes.STRING, },
    }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: "Question_answer",
        defaultScope: {
            attributes: { exclude: ["createdAt", "updatedAt"] }
        },
    });
    return Question_answer;
};
```

Fixed `Controller.js`

```
Component.findAll({ include: [{ all: true }], where: { module_id: module_id } })
    .then(async function (components) {
        for (var i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
            if (components[i].dataValues.question_id != null) {
                var answers = Question_answer.findAll({ where: { question_id: components[i].dataValues.question_id } })
                // ...
                // ...
            }
        }
    })
    .catch.error(onError);
```

But, I prefer below code to JOIN two table: `Controller.js`

```
Component.findAll({ include: ['questions'], where: { module_id: module_id } })
    .then((components) => {
        components = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(components))
        components.forEach(component => {
            var questions = component.questions || [];
            questions.forEach(q => {
                //access question item with 'q'
                console.log(q)
            })
        });
    })
    .catch.error(onError);
```